# Why I need to enumerate my list inside the program's logic for it to work in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

I have this simple piece of code:

```
IEnumerable<AccessData> reports = _model.GetAllAccessEvents();
foreach (var ap in AccessPoints.Where(x => !x.IsChecked))
    reports = reports.Where(x => x.AccessPointId != ap.Id);
```

It should remove the non checked objects from the `reports` IEnumerable. But it doesn't work (it returns the complete list). Unless I do this:

```
foreach (var ap in AccessPoints.Where(x => !x.IsChecked))
    reports = reports.Where(x => x.AccessPointId != ap.Id).**ToList()**;
```

Then the results come properly filtered. Why do I need to enumerate my results in the middle of the logic for it to work?

Comment: Never try to bind to a foreach variable in a lambda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413706/how-does-a-lambda-in-c-sharp-bind-to-the-enumerator-in-a-foreach

Comment: @mihi: Well, not unless you're using a C# 5 compiler.

Comment: This could also probably be done without the foreach, perhaps with a Zip.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good to know that they eventually fix common pitfalls. When will they fix that saving a Metafile as WMF converts it first to pixels and then back? :)

Comment: @mihi: Well that's not a *language* issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you do not *need* to enumerate your data in a loop in order to make it work (although it is one of the ways to fix the problem). The reason why it does not work without the `ToList` is that the code in the inner `Where` refers to a modified closure - variable `ap` which is modified in a loop.

Using a temporary variable for it would fix the problem:

```
IEnumerable<AccessData> reports = _model.GetAllAccessEvents();
foreach (var ap in AccessPoints.Where(x => !x.IsChecked)) {
    var theId = ap.Id; // Introduce a temporary variable
    reports = reports.Where(x => x.AccessPointId != theId);
}
```

Another solution would be using a `Where` that compares `AccessPointId`s to all items in the access events without a loop, like this:

```
reports = _model
    .GetAllAccessEvents()
    // The condition ensures that x is such that its ID is not present
    // among the AccessPointIds of the checked access points:
    .Where(x => !AccessPoints.Any(ap => ap.IsChecked && ap.AccessPointId == x.Id));
```

Comment: `Any` is an implicit inner loop; `Join` would perform better for large numbers of elements.

Answer (score 2):

What version of C# are you using?  The behavior of a loop variable in a closure changed with C# 5 (if I recall correctly).  If this is indeed your problem, then the following should work, too:

```
IEnumerable<AccessData> reports = _model.GetAllAccessEvents();
foreach (var ap in AccessPoints.Where(x => !x.IsChecked))
{
    var closureAp = ap;
    reports = reports.Where(x => x.AccessPointId != closureAp.Id);
}
```

More efficent, perhaps, though less concise (assumes the type of Id is `int`; change as needed):

```
var reports = _model.GetAllAccessEvents().ToList();
var idsToRemove = new HashSet<int>(AccessPoints.Where(x => !x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Id));
reports.RemoveAll(report -> idsToRemove.Contains(report.AccessPointId));
```

or

```
var reports =
    from accessPoint in AccessPoints
    where !accessPoint.IsChecked
    join accessEvent in _model.GetAllAccessEvents()
        on accessPoint.Id equals accessEvent.AccessPointId
    select accessEvent;
```

Note that using `Join` or HashSet will give the algorithm better time complexity, meaning that its performance will deteriorate less rapidly as the number of elements grows.

Comment: My question was more about an explanation than optimization, but thanks, this will help me because the `_model.GetAllAccessEvents()` may return a very large number of elements.